# Error : Tiled GPU perf. warning

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently ran into this problem.
I imported a model (mesh + armature) and, when a pressed play, this message appeared:

`Tiled GPU perf. warning: RenderTexture color surface  (1246x535) was not cleared/discarded, doing <run with profiler for info>`

It gives me fps problems and slows the shadows processing.
I've tried to delete the model, but it doesen't seem the cause of the problem.
I've also found other posts that concern similar topics but they don't give a solution.

[EDIT]
The problem occur only in perspective view (ortographic is fine)

Unity version : 5.5.0f3

Comment: Are you suing none standard shader? Maybe a shader from the the internet? Do you have one of the image effect scripts attached to your camera? What happens if you delete the camera then create a new one and then restart Unity?

Comment: standard legacy diffuse shader, no image effects, the new camera has the same problem

Comment: Haven't ran into this problem before. What happens if you create new project? I think it would be good to mention your Unity version.

Comment: With the new project was all fine. But when i built it for android "Tiled GPU perf" appeared.

Comment: I can't think of anything other than a bug. File for a bug report from the Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Just change setting of Unity:
Edit -> Graphic Emulation -> No Emulation